# IP address and domain restrictions in iis through powershell

Tags: .net, windows, security, iis, powershell

I am very new in `powershell`.

How to change `ip address and domain restrictions` in IIS through `powershell`.

Here is the screen shot how we can manualy do this from IIS.

[image]

Currently I am using this code to change the settings.

`Set-WebConfigurationProperty /system.webserver/security/ipsecurity -Name allowUnlisted -Value "true" -Location "IIS:\Sites\123" -pspath IIS:\Sites\123`

Don't know this is correct or not.

Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: This code will toggle *Access for unspecified clients* value so it is correct in that respect. Use it without -PSPath and it will work

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty /system.webserver/security/ipsecurity -Name allowUnlisted -Value "true" -Location "IIS:\Sites\123"
```

Comment: Getting this error `This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny")` when changing value

Comment: After removing -PSPath, error is not coming. But the change is not reflecting in iis.

Comment: You have to refresh your GUI, ie come out of the feature and come back in or restart IIS manager to verify. It works on IIS 8/8.5, what version are you running?

Comment: After changing to `-Location "/123"` working fine. is this right way?

Comment: That will work too, I guess you can compare the difference to a filesystem - relative path vs full path (though not _exactly _ the same).
Using the full path - e.g. IIS:\Sites\123 - is seen as a better solution as it avoids ambiguity.